# Access to path is denied - File.Move fails but File.Delete works

Tags: c#, system.io.file, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm trying to perform a simple `File.Move` operation but I get

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException exception - Access to the path is denied.

To my knowledge, nothing is using the file I am trying to move (containing folder is closed as well). I can move the file manually via File Explorer just fine. I've tried `File.Delete` and it works perfectly fine.

I'm unsure of what is happening - why would `File.Move` fail but `File.Delete` work if Visual Studio says that access to the path is denied?

Here is my code:

```
string file = @"C:\Data\VCR\150326\150326.MPG";
string destination = @"G:\ArchiveData\Video";

System.IO.File.Move(file, destination);
```

Comment: Have you tried to access (or create/delete) any file(s) on the destination folder? Try some code to do something on that folder, that might be the conflicting one

Comment: Put a trailing backslash on `destination`, so that it's clear it's a directory and not a filename. Windows thinks you're trying to copy the file `150326.MPG` to `G:\ArchiveData\Video` ( a file named Video) instead of copying it to the folder `Video\`, and if the folder already exists then clearly the copy to that filename will fail.

Answer (score 13):

So my problem was that my destination path did not include the file name. Adding the filename to my variable `destination` makes it work:

```
string file = @"C:\Data\VCR\150326\150326.MPG";
string destination = @"G:\ArchiveData\Video\150326.MPG";

System.IO.File.Move(file, destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your anti virus software. It may be blocking the file move.